# Adding toolbar to grid and set its position above the tbar of Ext.grid.GridPanel

Tags: extjs3

I have a `grid`:

```
ProjectListReportGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
    iconCls: 'silk-grid',
    id: 'consolidatedReportGrid',
    frame: false,
    title: 'Project Team Reports[Team Summary Report]',
    initComponent: function () {

        this.viewConfig = {
            forceFit: true
        };

        this.tbar = this.buildBottomToolbar();
        ProjectListReportGrid.superclass.initComponent
            .call(this);
    },
    buildBottomToolbar: function () {
        teamSummaryReportButton = new Ext.Button({
            iconCls: 'teamsummaryreport',
            handler: this.onAdd,
            scope: this,
            name: 'Summary'
        });
    }
});
```

---

and I added a new `toolbar` to above `grid` as shown below:

```
consolidatedReportGrid.add(new Ext.Toolbar({
    width: 1300,
    id: 'remove',
    buttonAlign: 'center',
    tabPosition: 'top',
    items: [myRadioGroup]
}));
```

I want to set its position to top but it is coming below `tbar` of `gridpanel`.

Comment: Please verify your version of ExtJS, you labled your question as ExtJS3 and ExtJS5 at the same time.

Comment: @ sergey-novikov its extjs 3

Comment: You can't dynamically add docked items in Ext 3 or below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For ExtJS3**

Use [`insert()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-insert) instead of [`add()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-add), like this:

```
grid.getTopToolbar().insert(0, new Ext.Toolbar({
    items: [
        new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Added button'
        })
    ]
}));
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b2k)

**For ExtJS4+**

Use [`addDocked()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-addDocked) instead of [`add()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-add), like this:

```
grid.addDocked(new Ext.Toolbar({
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Test add docked'
        }
    ]
}), 0);
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1b23)

Comment: Its  not working for extjs 3 version.. @SergeyNovikov

Comment: Yup, for ExtJS3 it should not work. Well, im not familiar with ExtJS3, but I guess you can add toolbar to your `tbar` config (and update lyout if grid is already rendered). @ShivakumarNH

Comment: Can u give me a sample code for this..@SergeyNovikok

Comment: I check ExtJS3 docs and create simple fiddle, check it. But now I actually realzie that I was wrong... You want your component *above* `tbat`, not at top of its items. Anyway, check my fiddle, maybe this solution satisfy you. @ShivakumarNH